# Add a $ dollar sign in front of the number printed by plotchar()

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am using pinescript v5 to print out a number `num_size`. The code looks something like this;

```
plotchar(num_size, title="num_size", char="", location=location.top, color=color.yellow)
```

I want to add a dollar sign in front of the number to be printed.

I don't mind answers that use alternative solution like `label_new()`

Comment: Is `num_size` the "number" in question here?

Comment: @vitruvius, yes.

Comment: Have you looked into the arguments plotchar can accept? The "text" may warrant some attention.

Comment: Well, it cannot be a string.

Comment: Hi, I'm not very familiar with pine-script, but decided to take a look out of curiosity. 
As you've already indicated, it appears that `label.new` can do this, however for someone that's not familiar with pine-script, it's not immediately obvious how to coincide this with a value from `plotchar(...)`.   For example, the example provided shows a yellow line for me.  This makes it hard to know if a solution provided would be acceptable.  I'm happy to share my solution in an answer, but I am hesitant to in fear of downvoting: https://gist.github.com/tresf/0793d8c152028a59e60ff372a50d2c9f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that with `plotchar()` as the name suggests, it works with a `char` and not with a `string`.

Since you mentioned you are open to alternative solutions, here are four ways to do it with a `label`.

The first example uses `str.format()`. This will format the number and add the $ in front.

The second example uses a hard-coded approach.

The third example puts the currency of the symbol in front. It will not be a dollar sign but USD instead. You can convert the return value to currency signs if you need because this is the most reliable option in my opinion -which is option four.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

f_conver_currency_to_sign(p_currency) =>
    switch (p_currency)
        "EUR" => "€"
        "USD" => "$"
        "GBP" => "£"
        => p_currency

if (barstate.islast)
    s = "Close 1: " + str.format("{0,number,currency}", close) + "\n"
    s := s + "Close 2: " + "$" + str.tostring(close, format.mintick) + "\n"
    s := s + "Close 3: " + syminfo.currency + str.tostring(close) + "\n"
    s := s + "Close 4: " + f_conver_currency_to_sign(syminfo.currency) + str.tostring(close)
    label.new(bar_index, high, s, textcolor=color.white)
```

As you can see below, options 1 and 2 will fail on `EURGBP`:

[image]

`EURUSD`:
[image]